# login por roles

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy intentando hacer un login con el framework codeigniter 3, cada usuario tiene diferente rol. Pude hacer que todos los usuarios puedan ingresar al sistema si estan dentro de la base de datos, si no estan dentro de la db simplemente los manda de regreso al login, pero estoy tratando hacer que dependiendo del rol que tenga el usuario lo mande a una vista diferente.

Este es el codigo de las tablas que estoy ocupando en la base de datos:

```
create table roles(
    id_rol int auto_increment primary key not null,
    nombre varchar (50),
    descripcion varchar (50)
);
create table usuarios(
    id_usuarios int auto_increment primary key not null,
    usuario varchar (50),
    nombre varchar (30),
    status bool,
    cambiar_pass bool,
    pin varchar (10),
    contrasenia varchar (50),
    correo varchar (50),
    cel varchar (30),
    rol_id int,
    constraint foreign key (rol_id) references roles (id_rol)
);
```

Este es el modelo que ya tengo hecho:

```
class Administracion extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database('portafolio');
    }
    public function login($user = "usuario", $pass = '$%&')
    {
        $sql = "SELECT usuario , contrasenia FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user));
        $data = $query->row(); // $query->result();
        if (isset($data->contrasenia) && $data->contrasenia == $pass) {
            //echo ($data->contrasenia);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Y finalmente, este es el controlador que estoy ocupando:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('administracion');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        //session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            header("Location: /portafolio/Login");
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST['txtUsuario']) && isset($_POST['txtPassword'])) {
                $login = $this->administracion->login($_POST['txtUsuario'], $_POST['txtPassword']);
                if ($login == true) {
                    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                    header("Location: proyectos");
                    //echo ($_POST['txtPassword']);
                    //echo ('Bienvenido ') . $_POST['txtUsuario'];
                } else {
                    $this->load->view('login');
                }
            } else {
                $this->load->view('login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `->login()` debería devolver datos del usuario en caso de encontrarlo:

```
class Administracion extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database('portafolio');
    }
    public function login($user = "usuario", $pass = '$%&')
    {
        $sql = "SELECT usuario , contrasenia FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user));
        $data = $query->row(); // $query->result();
        if (isset($data->contrasenia) && $data->contrasenia == $pass) {
            // Devolver información de usuario
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

En el controlador ya puedes analizar el rol y crear variables de sesión adecuadas para futuras comprobaciones:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('administracion');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        //session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            header("Location: /portafolio/Login");
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST['txtUsuario']) && isset($_POST['txtPassword'])) {
                $login = $this->administracion->login($_POST['txtUsuario'], $_POST['txtPassword']);
                // $login puede ser falso o datos del usuario
                if ($login !== false) {
                    // Se recibieron datos, el login es correcto
                    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                    // Crea un arreglo para saber qué usuario está conectado
                    // Agrega la información que creas necesaria
                    $_SESSION['user'] = [
                        'id' => $data->id_usuarios,
                        'nombre' => $data->nombre,
                        'rol' => $data->rol_id
                    ];
                    // Comparas el rol para saber qué hacer
                    if($data->rol_id == 1) {
                        // Supongamos que es administrador
                        header('Location: administracion');
                        exit; // Debes finalizar el script
                    } elseif($data->rol_id == 2) {
                        // Supongamos que es moderador
                        header('Location: moderacion');
                        exit;
                    }
                    // Usuario normal
                    header("Location: proyectos");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $this->load->view('login');
                }
            } else {
                $this->load->view('login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En páginas donde necesites que el usuario tenga un rol definido para poder acceder:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user']['rol'] != 1) {
    // El usuario no es administrador
    header('Location: pagina_por_defecto');
    exit;
}
// Aquí todo lo que puede hacer el administrador
```

**Importante:** En la tabla de usuarios tienes una columna `status` y creo que deberías realizar una validación para confirmar que el usuario está activo, probablemente antes de crear las variables de sesión.